# Golang read line and then read word from same bufio.Scanner

Tags: go

I'm trying to read a line and words from stdin using the same `bufio.Scanner` instance.

I've tried using two `bufio.Scanner` first but it the second scanner can't read anything.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    r := strings.NewReader("first line\n2nd line")
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(r)
    scanner2 := bufio.NewScanner(r)

    fmt.Println("scanning line")
    if scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println("Scanned line: ", scanner.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }

    scanner2.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    fmt.Println("scanning word")
    if scanner2.Scan() {
        // i'm expecting that this would read "2nd"
        fmt.Println("Scanned word: ", scanner2.Text())
    }

    if err := scanner2.Err(); err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintln(os.Stderr, "reading standard input:", err)
    }
}
```

Then I tried setting the `scanner.Split` , but it doesn't allow calling the `scanner.Split` after calling `scanner.Scan`.

Is there a way that I can read a line and then words from the same `bufio.Scanner`?

Comment: You might find it easier to read each line as a string with the scanner (see [example](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#example_Scanner_lines)), then split the line into words with [strings.Fields](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Fields)

Comment: @Mark, I decided to take your suggestion, i used it in [this](https://github.com/steven-ferrer/gonsole/commit/4b515577162f24402006f355dace561bc0ed4a10) project, please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

First. You can't read same line from reader multiple times. You read it once reader going to be empty, that is why the second scanner can't read anything. In your example you are using `strings.Reader` no `os.Stdin`. You can use something like `io.TeeReader` to duplicate to read the reader more times but this isn't your case.

Second. You cant call `scanner.Split` after `scanner.Scan` was called, you need to create a new scanner with `os.Stdin` as input.

For example:

```
// this gonna read from stdin complete lines
scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

// scanning lines until Q is typed
for scanner.Scan() {
    t := scanner.Text()

    if t == "Q" {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
}

// new scanner to read but this time words
scanner = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

for scanner.Scan() {
    fmt.Println(scanner.Text()) // Println will add back the final '\n'
}
```